# Authenticating and Creating a Bucket with Autodesk Forge API

Tags: c#, asp.net, autodesk-forge

I am in the process of learning the Autodesk Forge API. With a simple C# application, I am able to authenticate using the Forge API.

```
var responseString = await 
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate"
                                .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new
                                {
                                    client_id = Client_ID.Text,
                                    client_secret = Client_Secret.Text,
                                    grant_type = "client_credentials",
                                    scope = "data:read data:write bucket:create bucket:read"
                                })
                                .ReceiveJson();
```

Though I have explicitly specified the bucket:read scope bucket:read, further call to check a bucket exists fails with error:-

> Http code 403 (Forbidden) with the message "Only the bucket creator is allowed to access this API"

When I try to create another bucket with the same name it fails with the:-

> Http Code 409 (Conflict) with the message "Bucket already exists"

Can someone please help me on what is missing here?

Comment: The bucket you are trying to access is created by you only?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, No, before creating the bucket, I am calling the API to check if it exists (hoping that it will return an Bucket does not exist) but the error message is different. I looked around the API docs, and it looks like the name should be unique not just in your application but across all applications.

Comment: So, basically I tried with some long name, after few tries I was able to create a bucket with my unique name. What is confusing is, why they enforce this uniqueness across all applications.

Comment: It's just a limitation of the service at the moment unfortunately, so just try to come up with unique names, you can generate GUID-like names pretty easily with any random feature of the language you are using or use your Forge ClientID as prefix or suffix to your bucket name: "bucket1-<YOUR-CLIENT-ID-HERE>". Hope that helps.

Comment: @PhilippeLeefsma, Thank you. Currently I am using some random names, but will try to follow the convention as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that your bucket key should be globally unique across all application and regions. You can check the doc at https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/ for the detail, especially for the description of Bucket Key.

Comment: Thank you. I will go with the pattern suggested by "Philippe" to form the unique name.